# Почему для чётных нечётных чисел работает, а для чётных нет?

Tags: javascript

parseInt(window.location.href.replace(/\D/g, ''),10) //Из example.com/example/30/dsadfsb в 30

Для чётных работает, для нечётных отдаёт бредятину вроде 3.300000008070019e+78 (из 30и)

**UPD** Проблема в replace(/\D/g, ''), из 33 делает 33000000080700186081800000051800502051811820800018018318118100809018000501820000

Comment: у меня все работает. Поставил:

> parseInt("example.com/example/33/dsadfsb".replace(/\D/g, ''),10) 

возвращает 33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает верно, но если у вас в url есть escape-последовательности, то вы получите такой "глюк".

Вот так вы видите в адресной строке
[Почему для чётных нечётных чисел работает, а для чётных нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242359/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

Но на самом деле url выглядит так:
[Почему для чётных нечётных чисел работает, а для чётных нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242359/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

и выполнив `window.location.href.replace(/\D/g, '')`
получим `2423590018705018304018187191182018185005187191182018185187081810501800001018200051820004018187191182018185005182`

Comment: Да, проблема в этом. Но как её исправить?

Comment: Что значит исправить? не делать так например. Ваш подход не верен, такой способ извлечения цифр из урл багаемкий по умолчанию. Но можно попробовать так `parseInt((location.href.toString().match(/[^%](\d+)/)||[,0])[1], 10)`